# Netlogo, creating turtles from a list 1, and then moving them to coordinates in list 2

Tags: netlogo

I have two lists, one list contains gis vertex values (x,y coordinates) i.e values [(1.16,17.70),(1.17,19,5),(1.18,21.41),(5.04,15.79)....]. 
The other list containing the number of turtles I want to create i.e [34,146,195,361]
I want to create the number of turtles and move them to this location. i.e the first 34 turtles to be created and move to (1.16,17.70).

Any ideas how to do that?
Thanks

```
set loc-coord [....]                              
set pop-num [....]

foreach pop-num [
i ->
create-pop-agents i[
move-to loc-coord
]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You're more or less there- you can just use the second version of the [foreach syntax](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/foreach.htmll) (`(foreach list1 ... command)`) to iterate over both lists at the same time:

```
to setup
  ca
  let coords [ [ -10 -10 ] [ -5 -5 ] [ 0 0 ] [ 5 5 ]  [ 10 10 ] ]
  let ns [ 1 2 3 4 5 ]

  ( foreach coords ns [
    [ c n ] ->
    crt n [
      setxy first c last c 
    ]
  ])
  reset-ticks
end
```

[image]